# How to disable "Page" feature in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, powershell

How to disable "Page" feature from

> Site Actions->More Options->In All Items Page-> Page in SharePoint 2010 ?

Can anyone please suggest a power-shell script or a feature to deactivate user from creating new pages?

**[Update]**

I need to remove the red squared feature for all the users from a web application .It is a basic type of page . Can you suggest a powershell script with which i can remove this Basic Type Page for all the users of a web application .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deactivating user from creating new pages is related to your **permission setting** that assigned to this user, so you have to deactivate "create new page" by assigning on of the following permission level :

- **Read**. (  Can view pages and list items and download documents.)
- Or **Limited access**.(Can view specific lists, document libraries, list items, folders, or documents when given permissions.)
- Or **View Only**. (Can view pages, list items, and documents. Document types with server-side file handlers can be viewed in the browser but not downloaded.)
- Or **Restricted Read** (Can view pages and documents, but cannot view historical versions or user permissions.)
- Or **custom permission level** with disallowing create new page with uncheck

> Add and Customize Pages  -  Add, change, or delete HTML pages or Web Part Pages, and edit the Web site using a Microsoft SharePoint
>   Foundation-compatible editor.

To check the permissions levels , navigate yo `http://yourwebroot/_layouts/15/role.aspx`

Comment: Hello , Thanks for instant reply . Consider myself as super admin and i don't want any user to add a page through Site Actions->More Options->In All Items Page-> Page . Want to remove the "Page " functionality for most of users .

Comment: please should you update your question with a screenshot to avoid any confusing

Comment: Dear @RohitKharade  I think  , you can't achieve something like this without using permission , but you can deploy event receiver to prevent creating new page based on your requirement .

Comment: I searched further and realized that it is a wiki page having "SPLISTTEMPLATETYPE" id 119(Wiki Page Library)  . Can we hide this icon by using css and jvascript ?